# Query MongoDB with multiples filters in subarrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to all documents **which the last event of category Temperatures is technicalFailure even if there are other events after this one**.

To give more context, the query is the result of a http request with query parameters. If receives technicalFailure, we should return all documents **which the last event of category Temperatures is technicalFailure whatever the next events of different category** (for instance, category "Payment" with event "failed")

Therefore, another event with different category could be the last event in `events` array.

I am trying to use the operator `$filter` like below, but it is not working expectedly

```
{
  $and: [
    {
      "transports.events.category": "Temperatures",
      "transports.events.event": "technicalFailure"
    },
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$transports[0].events",
                  cond: {
                    $and: [
                      { $eq: ["$$this.category", "Temperatures"] },
                      { $eq: ["$$this.event", "technicalFailure"] }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              -1
            ]
          },
          {
            category: "Temperatures",
            event: "technicalFailure"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone can help for this query ?

The sample of documents :

```
[
  {
    transports: [
      {
        _id: "123",
        events: [
          {
            category: "Payment",
            event: "ok",
            date: "2023-02-21T16:32:07.740Z"
          },
          {
            category: "Temperatures",
            event: "technicalFailure",
            date: "2023-02-21T16:36:07.740Z"
          },
          {
            category: "Payment",
            event: "failed",
            date: "2023-02-21T16:55:07.740Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    transports: [
      {
        _id: "456",
        events: [
          {
            category: "Payment",
            event: "ok",
            date: "2023-02-21T16:28:07.740Z"
          },
          {
            category: "Temperatures",
            event: "auto",
            date: "2023-02-21T16:29:07.740Z"
          },
          {
            category: "Payment",
            event: "failed",
            date: "2023-02-21T17:01:07.740Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    transports: [
      {
        _id: "127",
        events: [
          {
            category: "Payment",
            event: "ok",
            date: "2023-02-21T16:29:07.740Z"
          },
          {
            category: "Temperatures",
            event: "auto",
            date: "2023-02-21T17:18:07.740Z"
          },
          {
            category: "Temperatures",
            event: "technicalFailure",
            date: "2023-02-21T18:53:07.740Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The expected result :

```
[
  {
    transports: [
      {
        _id: "123",
        events: [
          {
            category: "Payment",
            event: "ok",
            date: "2023-02-21T16:32:07.740Z"
          },
          {
            category: "Temperatures",
            event: "technicalFailure",
            date: "2023-02-21T16:36:07.740Z"
          },
          {
            category: "Payment",
            event: "failed",
            date: "2023-02-21T16:55:07.740Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    transports: [
      {
        _id: "127",
        events: [
          {
            category: "Payment",
            event: "ok",
            date: "2023-02-21T16:29:07.740Z"
          },
          {
            category: "Temperatures",
            event: "auto",
            date: "2023-02-21T17:18:07.740Z"
          },
          {
            category: "Temperatures",
            event: "technicalFailure",
            date: "2023-02-21T18:53:07.740Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your updated requirements, here's one way you could do it.  Comments are in the aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { // eliminate docs without possibility of match
    "$match": {
      "transports.events": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "category": "Temperatures",
          "event": "technicalFailure"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // check final condition of remaining docs
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$transports",
          "initialValue": false,
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                // set the last "Temperatures" event
                "lastEvent": {
                  "$last": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$$this.events",
                      "as": "event",
                      "cond": {
                        "$eq": ["$$event.category", "Temperatures"]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "in": {
                "$or": [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    "$eq": ["$$lastEvent.event","technicalFailure"]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8OvxqLUQU_p).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, to fulfill your 2nd condition that last element is of category "Temperatures" and have the event "technicalFailure", the 1st condition must also be fulfilled at the same time. So, it boils to checking the 2nd condition only and we only need to check last element in array. We can then proceed to extract the last element with `$last` and chain it up with `$anyElementTrue` for array processing.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "lastEvent": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$transports",
          "as": "t",
          "in": {
            $last: "$$t.events"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        "$anyElementTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$lastEvent",
            "as": "le",
            "in": {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$le.category",
                    "Temperatures"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$le.event",
                    "technicalFailure"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "lastEvent"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H2vZL_tuSI8)

Comment: Actually, another event with different category could be the last event in array. So the query is not right.
To give more context, the query is the result of a http request with query parameters. If receives technicalFailure, we should return all documents which the last event of category Temperatures is technicalFailure whatever the next events of different category.

Comment: @tboll I understood your requirements the same way that ray did. Please update your question to clarify. Which of your sample documents should match? (And do you have examples of docs that shouldn't?)

Comment: I have edited the question. At the end, we will find the sample documents and the result expected